# Where to get free seafloor elevation data

Tags: bathymetry, data, south-america

While I have found multiple sources for continental elevation layers, I have been unable to find sea-floor elevation layers.

Specifically, I'm looking for data for the sea-floor around southern South America.

Comment: Question for [Stack exchange: open data](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Which resolution do you need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[GEBCO](http://www.gebco.net/data_and_products/) provides an homogeneous coverage of the world seabed.

Answer (score 2):

[vterrain](http://vterrain.org/Elevation/Bathy/) has a list of available bathymetry datasets which is a good starting point.

The USGS has a large amount of freely available bathymetry datasets - [also covering Argentina](http://walrus.wr.usgs.gov/infobank/v/v1060sa/html/v-10-60-sa.meta.html)

Depending on your resolution requirements the 1-arc second [ETOPO1](https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/global/global.html) also contains seafloor elevation.